# Android Auto Desktop Head Unit tool: Parked vs Driving?

Tags: android, android-auto

Recent versions of Android Auto limited the number of MediaItems an app could display "for safety reasons".   The latest version of Android Auto (v1.6) changed this message and it now indicates the user can see more items when the car is "parked".

Is there a command for the Desktop Head Unit tool that will toggle parked/not-parked?

The Help command does not list an option but surely there must be a way to simulate the car being stationary/parked?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted to Android Auto Google+ Community:
https://plus.google.com/+RobertNekic/posts/UPBL46iyAAS

Comment: Created Feature Request for future DHU update:  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206069